# cannot post using sequelize and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I cannot get my post meetingtype route to work.  the problem seems to be between my model and my DAO as some of my code tweaking got MeetingType.create is not a function errors.  Currently I just get Cannot POST /api/meetingtype in insomnia.  The Sequelize create is not a function answers on stack overflow arn't helping.  Here is my code:

```
//database/index
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const DB = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  storage: 'C:/Users/bubblegum/Desktop/programming projects/Oconnell/database/db.db',
  define: {timestamps: false}
  }
); 
module.exports.DB = DB;
```

```
//models/meetingtype.js
'use strict';
const DB = require('../database/index');
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes, INTEGER} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (DB, DataTypes) => {
  class MeetingType extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  MeetingType.init({
    MeetingTypeID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    MeetingTypeDescription: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    DB,
    modelName: 'MeetingType',
  });
  return MeetingType;
};
```

```
/DAO/MeetingTypeDAO.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); // attempt to get create to work
const DB = require('../database/index').DB;
const MeetingType = require('../models/MeetingType');
var MeetingTypeDao = {
     create: create
}

function create(MeetingType) {   
     
    MeetingType.create(MeetingType).then(NewMeetingType => { //MeetingType is json of not autoincrement properties
         return NewMeetingType;
     });
}
module.exports = MeetingTypeDao;
```

```
//controllers/MeetingTypeController.js
const MeetingTypeDao = require('../DAO/MeetingTypeDao');
var MeetingTypeController = {
    addMeetingType: addMeetingType
}
function addMeetingType(req, res) {
    MeetingTypeDao.create(req.body). //json of non autoincrement MeetingType properties
    then((MeetingType) => {
        res.send(MeetingType);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
module.exports = MeetingTypeController;
```

```
//routers/MeetingTypeRouter
const Express = require('express');
const router = Express.Router();
const MeetingTypeController = require('../Controllers/MeetingTypeController');
router.post('/', MeetingTypeController.addMeetingType);
module.exports = router;
```

```
//app.js
const Express = require('express');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const {DB} = require('./database');
let app = Express();
const MeetingTypeRouter = require('./routers/MeetingTypeRouter');
app.use(Express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(Express.json());
app.use('api/meetingtype', MeetingTypeRouter);

DB.authenticate().then(()=>{
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(err => console.log("Error: " + err));
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
try {
  app.listen(PORT, console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));  
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error);
};
```

Comment: You have to do this `return MeetingType.create(MeetingType)` in MeetingTypeDAO.js

Comment: still not working after i changed function create(meetingtypeobject) to: return MeetingType.create(meetingtypeobject);

Comment: Can you do a simple console.log() to check if the `MeetingTypeController.addMeetingType` controller is being called or not?

Comment: I replaced then contents of addMeetingType with just :console.log(MeetingTypeDao.create(req.body));  still got cannot post error and nothing logged to the console

Comment: Can you change to this: `app.use('/api/meetingtype', MeetingTypeRouter);`?

Comment: progress: got the meetingtype.create is not a function error back

Comment: Great! Now check if your filename is correct or not here: `const MeetingType = require('../models/MeetingType');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230585/discussion-between-mazoula-and-rifat-bin-reza).